# SQL Databases and Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an assessment for my computer science masters. They give you 3 tables and ask you to write SQL statements to build the tables in MySQL. Please see [link](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/pjr/co887/assessment1.html) for assignment.

I am struggling with writing the foreign and primary keys for Booking. I am aware that I need the perftime and date as foreign keys but I feel I also need the row number.. however I believe Foreign keys are for connecting two tables together.

Also, the primary key should be the Booking Id as it is the only unique item but it mentions in the assignment only to include what’s in the tables.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current attempt.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images - or, even worse, links to images.

Answer (score 0):

To make good table, you need a booking id. But in this situation, it isn't allowed. So now you have to put the pk on the column: 
-perfDate
-perfTime
-Rownumber (otherwise you can't create an unique primary key in the table 'booking')

You need to set the foreign key in table performance to booking on the columns perfDate and perfTime.

You don't need a fk on the row number. The row number is part of the composite primary key.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This has cleared things up and the above user said the same. I was unaware I could use the PK as Rownumber aswell, especially as this is the PK for the Seat table.

Comment: Do you know if I can declare my FK's like below. CREATE TABLE Booking (
Email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,  
PerfDate CHAR(10),
PerfTime CHAR(8),
RowNumber CHAR(3),  
PRIMARY KEY (PerfDate, PerfTime, RowNumber)
FOREIGN KEY (PerfDate, PerfTime) REFERENCES Performance (PerfDate, PerfTime) 
FOREIGN KEY (RowNumber) REFERENCES Seat (RowNumber) 
);

Comment: So I have a composite key coming from Performance and another key coming from Seat.

Comment: Yes, but you have to put a comma, between the different foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment is actually telling you what the primary key is with the underlined fields. They have defined a composite key (a primary key which is a combination of columns rather than a singal column)

The primary key for booking is defined as `PerfDate,PerfTime,RowNumber`

The foreign key would be `PerfDate,PerfTime` which links to the primary key in the performance table which is a composite key comprising of those two columns. This is because one performance can have many bookings and each booking relates to only one performance

A performance does not have a row number column so that cannot be in your foreign key

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks for your help. 
I was unaware that I could have a primary key of 'row number' when the primary key of Seat is also 'row number'.

Comment: This has cleared things up for me. The lecturer has now taken BookingID off the conceptual model as this was misleading (and would usually be the only unique piece of date in the Booking table)

Comment: Primary keys are per table so what you do in one table in term of the primary key does not matter in terms of other tables. 
Although bear in mind that RowNumber is not the primary key of your booking table, it is part of a composite key

Comment: Great, thanks. 
I realise now that not all classes need a FK, only when relevant. In this case, Booking has 3 composite PK but no FK.

Comment: Do you know if I can reference foreign keys from multiple tables as below? So I have a composite key coming from Performance and another key coming from Seat. 
CREATE TABLE Booking (
Email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,  
PerfDate CHAR(10),
PerfTime CHAR(8),
RowNumber CHAR(3),  
PRIMARY KEY (PerfDate, PerfTime, RowNumber)
FOREIGN KEY (PerfDate, PerfTime) REFERENCES Performance (PerfDate, PerfTime) 
FOREIGN KEY (RowNumber) REFERENCES Seat (RowNumber) 
);

Comment: Do you mean have multiple foreign keys in one table? Yes, you can do that

Comment: Yes but Can I have a composite foreign key linking to one table and then another foreign key linking to another? And it would it be written as follows?...

Comment: FOREIGN KEY (PerfDate, PerfTime) REFERENCES Performance (PerfDate, PerfTime) FOREIGN KEY (RowNumber) REFERENCES Seat (RowNumber) )